# Configure Dancer from environment variables?

Tags: perl, docker, dancer

I'm new to Dancer, but I'm trying to configure it to work within a Docker container.  As a result, I need to pick up my database settings from the environment.

In my case, I have `DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR`, and `DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT` coming from Docker.  Unfortunately, the `Dancer::Plugin::Database` module is erroring before I can change the database to use those variables.

```
use Dancer ':syntax';
use Dancer::Plugin::Database;

if ($ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP}) {## Connected via docker.
    database->({
        driver => 'mysql',
        username => 'username',
        password => 'password',
        host => $ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR},
        port => $ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT},
        database => $ENV{DB_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE},
    });
}
```

So the question is, is there a good way to configure Dancer from environment variables, instead of through static YAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Runtime Configuration](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Database#RUNTIME-CONFIGURATION) in the `Dancer::Plugin::Database` docs:

> You can pass a hashref to the `database()` keyword to provide configuration details to override any in the config file at runtime if desired, for instance:
>
> `my $dbh = database({ driver => 'SQLite', database => $filename });`

You're adding a `->`, which causes an error. The following should work:

```
use Dancer ':syntax';
use Dancer::Plugin::Database;

if ($ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP}) {## Connected via docker.
    database({
        driver => 'mysql',
        username => 'username',
        password => 'password',
        host => $ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR},
        port => $ENV{DB_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT},
        database => $ENV{DB_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE},
    });
}
```

Comment: Great observation, and you're right.  However, if I do as your code suggests, `database->quick_select(...)` yields an error:  `Can't call method "quick_select" on an undefined`.  Is there not a way to keep the `database` global?

Comment: Digging into the code for `Dancer::Plugin::Database::Core`, it looks like you can get the same connection handle on subsequent calls to `database` by passing the same hashref of settings: "The key to use to store this handle in `%handles`. This will be either the name supplied to `database()`, the hashref supplied to `database()` (thus, as long as the same hashref of settings is passed, the same handle will be reused) or `$def_handle` if `database()` is called without args" Unfortunately, passing around a hashref of settings is really no different from passing around a database handle.

Comment: You might play around with adding the connection settings to `config` and keeping track of them there: [Accessing configuration information from your app](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Cookbook#Accessing-configuration-information-from-your-app). Or simply creating a wrapper for the `database` function that passes in the correct settings.

Comment: @JackM. `database()` returns handler, AFAIR, so you could save it into var like `$dbh = database( { driver => ... } )`

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your *lib/myapp.pm*, after module loading, add :

```
setting('plugins')->{'Database'}->{'host'}='postgres';
setting('plugins')->{'Database'}->{'database'}=$ENV{POSTGRES_DB};
setting('plugins')->{'Database'}->{'username'}=$ENV{POSTGRES_USER};
setting('plugins')->{'Database'}->{'password'}=$ENV{POSTGRES_PASSWORD};
```

and keep static config (Driver, port) in *config.yml*